# Increase display resolution beyond built in display native resolution OS X

Tags: macos, resolution, osx-mountain-lion

I was in an Apple Store yesterday and switched on AirDisplay on the 11" MacBook Air that I was playing with. A near-by 50" TV connected to an Apple TV soon flashed up the 11" Air display that I was seeing. Nothing too surprising there. However the resolution on the 11" screen scaled up to 1920x1080 (the resolution of the TV, I assume).

I had a play about in the Display prefpane but the way that ML lists resolutions has changed (Best for Built-In Display/Apple TV Display). Anyway, clearly OS X is capable of scaling screen resolution beyond the native resolution of the screen. Any idea if there's an app out there that lets you take advantage of that or if there's a way to do it in the CLI?

Answer (score 2):

It is funny you post this because i just searched google for 11" macbook air scaled resolution 1920x1080- the reason being that i am currently using my 11" macbook air at that resolution. There seems to be a bug where if your connection times out when selecting Airplay Mirroring, the resolution remains 1920x1080 on the laptop.

I actually kinda like this on the 11", it is definitely passable considering how much space you get. I am looking for ways to change or customize it to slightly smaller.